SEO: How is a javascript history.back link treated by search engines?
I have an back button on each page and subpage on my website.
I always takes the user to the previous page, no matter how many posts and redirects etc. happened on the subpage the user is on
Now I'm going away from using cookies on my site, and I also want to avoid using long urls (like adding queries: website.tld/subpage/?back=view&sub=xxxx&subsub=5 etc.), and this forces me to rethink the back button.
I think the best is to just let it go back to the main front page, and then use javascript window.history.back() to make sure the user always goes back to the relevant previous page.
But this can be less good when there are posts and redirects on the subpage.
How is a "back to previous page" seen/treated by search engines when the link has a javascript window.history.back()?
Is the javascript ignored and the actual link honored?
Or hm should I just remove the back link "button" alltogether and just let users use the browser back button? I think some would miss it..

I would highly recommend to stick on visible linked pagination with maintained rel="prev" / rel="next" head links, for better crawlability.
This is valid for all kinds of pagination:

category pages,
from one article to the other,
from one part of a single article to another part of the same article.

